# Why i'm not getting any beep sound in c++?

Tags: c++

I was reading about File I/O in C++. In the text book i found an example which creates beep sound whenever it prints "Enter password: ". But when i compile it in my linux codeblocks compiler it doesn't produce any sound.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

istream &getPass(istream &stream)
{
cout<<'\a';
cout<<"Enter password: ";
return stream;
}

int main()
{
char pow[80];
do
{
    cin>>getPass>>pow;
}
while(strcmp(pow,"pass"));
cout<<"Login Complete."<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is no instruction in this code which hint for anything sound related. Which text book is that? If the code above is really from that book, find another book.

Comment: '\a' produces beep sound

Comment: Try a different terminal if you have one. Sometimes the beep can be turned off.

Comment: Most terminal emulators don't produce beeps by default. You need to enable them in a terminal-specific way from yout settings menu.

Comment: Your code works, I just compiled it with VC on Windows 7.

Comment: okay, thanks all for your response.I'm using linux and my code compiles in XTerm terminal

Comment: also would recommend string::compare instead of strcmp.

Comment: Depends on your exact configuration but see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/228096/terminal-bell-doesnt-ring). How to enable system beeps is more an askubuntu-style question.

Comment: @IAmBlake retracting comment. missed the '\a' completely.